# VB .Net CODE for GoTo a specific line in richTextbox?

Tags: vb.net, richtextbox

I'm creating a Notepad in VB .NET
It's almost done!
But one thing left is GoTo
I don't found any code on WEB for GoTo (a specific line) in RichTextbox
Please someone tell me the CODE for GoTo a specific line!

Thanks

Comment: How about, instead of trying to find someone else's code on the web, you actually write dome of your own? Read the documentation for the `RichTextbox` class to see what methods and other members it has and then work out which ones to use in what combination to achieve your aim. That's called programming. We're not here to write your code for you. If you want to learn then make an attempt to learn and we can help you with specific issues when they arise. If you want someone else to write software for you, go and hire someone.

Comment: Thank you very much for inspiring and guiding me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
Private Sub ScrollToLine(ByVal lineNumber As Integer)
    If (lineNumber > richTextBox1.Lines.Count) Then
        Return
    End If

    richTextBox1.SelectionStart = richTextBox1.Find(richTextBox1.Lines(lineNumber))
    richTextBox1.ScrollToCaret
End Sub
```

Comment: How about instead of just downvoting it, you show me what you are trying to do and actually provide some code! Then I might be able to help you

Comment: My guess is that someone down-voted you for providing an answer to a question that is not appropriate for SO and therefore should not have been answered in the first place. This is a site for help with specific codding issues. If you provide answers to "write my code for me" questions then you simply encourage more of them, i.e. you are encouraging people to abuse this site.

Comment: FYI you are rewarded the [downvote privilege](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-down) at 125 reputation, so the OP couldn't possibly have made that vote. -- I have to agree with jmcilhinney though. Questions simply asking for code and showing no effort shouldn't be answered as they violate Stack Overflow's guidelines. This is most likely the reason why someone downvoted you.